# Merge two df with common column names by how='inner'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I'd like to merge dfa and dfb to create df_merged, but I want to merge columns that both have in common, rather than have the likes of A_x and A_y created.

**dfa**

```
    Name      A    B   C
0   Angel     1    2   3
1   Miguel    3    5   2
2   Rose      5    4   2
3   Gabe      3    5   3
```

**dfb**

```
    Name      A    B    D
0   Angel     1    2   53
1   Miguel    3    5   45
2   Fer       4    7   24
3   Gras      1    6   21
```

Expected **df_merge**

```
    Name      A    B   C   D
0   Angel     1    2   3  53
1   Miguel    3    5   2  45
```

I use `df_merge = dfa.merge(dfb,how="inner", on="Name")`

but instead i obtain

```
    Name      A_x   B_x   C   A_y  B_y   D
0   Angel     1      2    3    1    2   53
1   Miguel    3      5    2    3    5   45
```

I have been reading similar questions, but I don't have a solution of my problem. This is just an extract from my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns from both data frames are exactly the same, you have a duplicate. What you can do is add a common suffix to the columns of the second dataframe, and just drop the columns with those suffix after the merge.

```
dfc = dfa.merge(dfb,how="inner", on="Name", suffixes=(False,'_drop'))
```

Now just drop the columns which contain the word _drop in them.

```
dfc = dfc[dfc.columns.drop(list(dfc.filter(regex='_drop')))]
```